# Crear archivo txt en base a diccionario python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, diccionarios, txt

He creado un diccionario para reflejar los tramos de luz (valle,llana,punta) con sus respectivas horas.

Quiero crear un archivo .txt y mostrar una por una las horas indicando que tramo es.

Deberia de salir asi:

```
"La hora 0 es el tramo: valle"
"La hora 1 es el tramo: valle"
.
.
.
```

Así hasta la hora 23.

Tengo el siguiente código a medias pero no consigo entender como incluir el apartado de los tramos dentro del código.

```
file= open("tramos.txt", "w")
    tramos_horas= {(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7):"Valle",(8,9):"Llana",(10,11,12,13):"Punta",(14,15,16,17):"Llana",(18,19,20,21):"Punta",(22,23):"Llana"}
    for h in range(24):
        print(h)
        read.write("La hora {} es el tramo:\n".format(h))
    file.close()
    f= open("tramos.txt")
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="")
    f.close()
    print()
```

Actualmente me sale esto al correr el código:

```
La hora 0 es el tramo:
La hora 1 es el tramo:
La hora 2 es el tramo:
La hora 3 es el tramo:
La hora 4 es el tramo:
La hora 5 es el tramo:
La hora 6 es el tramo:
La hora 7 es el tramo:
La hora 8 es el tramo:
La hora 9 es el tramo:
La hora 10 es el tramo:
La hora 11 es el tramo:
La hora 12 es el tramo:
La hora 13 es el tramo:
La hora 14 es el tramo:
La hora 15 es el tramo:
La hora 16 es el tramo:
La hora 17 es el tramo:
La hora 18 es el tramo:
La hora 19 es el tramo:
La hora 20 es el tramo:
La hora 21 es el tramo:
La hora 22 es el tramo:
La hora 23 es el tramo:
```

Me echáis una mano?
Gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es tu estructura de datos. Actualmente `tramos_horas` es un diccionario que tiene como llave **tuplas**, no horas. Asi como esta, el diccionario no sirve para nada, pues lo que quieres es entregar una hora y obtener un texto.

La estructura propuesta para el diccionario es usar la hora como llave y el texto como valor. Para crear el diccionario usamos tres ciclos `for` por cada tipo de horario:

```
tramos_horas = {}
for hora in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "valle"
for hora in 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "llana"
for hora in 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "punta"
```

Ahora crear el archivo es directo, pues teniendo la hora, obtenemos el texto.

```
for h in range(24):
    file.write("La hora {} es el tramo: {}\n".format(h, tramos_horas[h]))
```

Eso no más.

#### Demo

```
file = open("tramos.txt", "w")
tramos_horas = {}
for hora in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "valle"
for hora in 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "llana"
for hora in 10, 11, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21:
    tramos_horas[hora] = "punta"

for h in range(24):
    file.write("La hora {} es el tramo: {}\n".format(h, tramos_horas[h]))
file.close()
f = open("tramos.txt")
for line in f:
    print(line, end="")
f.close()
print()
```

produce

```
La hora 0 es el tramo: valle
La hora 1 es el tramo: valle
La hora 2 es el tramo: valle
La hora 3 es el tramo: valle
La hora 4 es el tramo: valle
La hora 5 es el tramo: valle
La hora 6 es el tramo: valle
La hora 7 es el tramo: valle
La hora 8 es el tramo: llana
La hora 9 es el tramo: llana
La hora 10 es el tramo: punta
La hora 11 es el tramo: punta
La hora 12 es el tramo: punta
La hora 13 es el tramo: punta
La hora 14 es el tramo: llana
La hora 15 es el tramo: llana
La hora 16 es el tramo: llana
La hora 17 es el tramo: llana
La hora 18 es el tramo: punta
La hora 19 es el tramo: punta
La hora 20 es el tramo: punta
La hora 21 es el tramo: punta
La hora 22 es el tramo: llana
La hora 23 es el tramo: llana


Process finished with exit code 0
```